# replacing single quotation with double quotation

Tags: c#, replace

Having a bit of bother replacing single quotation with double quotation

```
so would like query to change from "partA LIKE 'true'" to "partA LIKE "true""
```

have tried

```
Query.Replace(@"'", @""");
Query.Replace("\'", "\\\"");
```

but ney joy

Ta

Comment: is this sql query ?

Comment: `Query.Replace("'", @"""");` or `Query.Replace("'","\"");`

Comment: no it is c# @mybirthname...I tried that Dmitry but it didnt work it returned \"true\"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
Query.Replace("'","\"");
```

Remember that .replace returns a string, and it don't change it directly, so assign it to another string like this:

```
String newString = oldString.Replace("'","\"");
```

Or use it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Query.Replace("'","\""));
```

Comment: so your final string is: **"partA LIKE \"true\""**

Comment: forgot to put the ? at the end

Comment: I got you!
The string ended like this: \"true\" because is a string, and it is needed (the \) because it is a string, and not part of the code. Try to print the code and u will see that is not \"true\" and it will be "true".
I Hope u understand me :)